# Connection between mql5 and visual studio

Tags: ide, mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I want to use visual studio ide instead of meta trader ide.. How to do that?

I mean writing and compiling code in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, your request is impossible.
Regarding different languages, that VS not know.
DId you ever heared that Microsoft VS deploy mql5 ?

You can write *.dll in VS to use this in MT5.

Have a fine day